# CGridView filtering/searching relations using joining table

Tags: php, relationship, yii, cgridview

I know there are a million and one thread on this subject, going through them I find differing information and can't find one specific to my problem, the over abundance of threads on this subject is actually less helpful than only having a handful. Please could someone take a few minutes to help.

I have 3 tables, here they are with relevant fields

```
Question (primary key = id)
Tag (primary key = id, text)
Question_Tag (question_id, tag_id)
```

**Question Model Relations**

```
     return array(
        'tags'=>array(
            self::MANY_MANY,
            'Tags',
            'question_tag(tag_id, question_id)'
        ),
        'question_tag'=>array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'QuestionTag',
            'question_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

**Tag Model relations**

```
     return array(
        'questions'=>array(
            self::MANY_MANY,
            'Questions',
            'question_tag(question_id, tag_id)'
        ),
        'question_tag'=>array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'QuestionTag',
            'tag_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

I have a CGridView, in this grid view I would like to display Question records (which I can do), I would also like to display, all tag records associated with each Question record's, 'text' field, so "tag.text", in the same column. I also need to be able to filter these tags, it doesn't matter if the actual searching/filtering of tags is done individually for each Question_Tag record, but displayed in the Grid they should be in the same column.

I can't for the life of me, after reading every wiki page, tutorial and forum thread, figure out how to do it. I can find fragments of the solution but I can't put them together. I've only been using Yii for a few days so I guess I don't understand it all properly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to handle this situation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [link](http://www.mrsoundless.com/php/yii/searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-cgridview/#comment-4939)

Comment: Thats great if you are only retrieving one record, but I'm not, I'm getting an array of CActiveRecords, for each of which I need the 'text' field.

Comment: You say you want tag.text in one column, does that mean it is ok to have multiple rows for the same question (with multiple tags)?  This will determine whether or not you have to serialize the tags for display (and potentially search).

Comment: No I dont want multiple rows, lets assume each question has 3 related Tag records, I wanted the Text fields of those 3 Tag records stored in the same column and row for the question. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Post the code you have in the controller action and view, so we have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, //Data Provider Of Quuestions
'columns'=>array(
            array(            
                        'name'=>'name',
                        'value'=>'$data->name',
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'tags'  
                'header'=>'Tags',
                'value'=>array($this,'displayRelatedTags'),
            ),),));
```

Above widget will call for displayRelatedTags function to display tags, So you have write following function in your respective controller

```
public function displayRelatedTags($data,$row)
{
foreach($data->tags as $tag) /*$data->tags is relation which you defined as MANY TO MANY in Questions class*/
{
$arrTags[]=$tag->text;
}
return implode(',',$arrTags); /*It will display comma sepearated tags in same row*/
}
```